# Customising the look of controls in Cappuccino

Tags: themes, cappuccino

I need to make a row of buttons on the bottom of the screen placed on what looks like a toolbar . But it should have a custom look ie. custom background and hover effects . I initially tried to customise a CPSegmentedControl but couldnt adjust the height of it as it uses fixed height graphics . Now I'm looking at trying out a toolbar but cant figure out how to change the background texture of the toolbar as it seems to be fixed . So which API is best suited for this ?

Answer (score 0):

This bit will change the CPToolBar background for you: https://github.com/cappuccino/issues/blob/master/Client/AppController.j#L273

If you want to customize the segmented control you can find code for that here: https://github.com/cappuccino/issues/blob/master/Client/AppController.j#L502

Comment: But how do you increase the height of the segmented control ? If you change that it seems to break it.

Comment: What I'm looking for is a set of custom buttons which have custom hover behaviour but they should act like a segmented control . Now I'll have to roll my own segmented control or try placing them on a toolbar.

Comment: You would have to supply your own images to the segmented control.